# What is the style of this arched window?

Tags: windows, architecture

What is the style of this arched window:

[image]

Is this just a modern design, or is it a specific historic style?

Answer (score 1):

Technically called, “Segmental Arch”. (A segment of a full 180 degree arch.)

Slang: “flat arch”.

Here’s some info:   http://csmh.pbworks.com/w/page/7309552/610%20-%20Chinese%20invent%20the%20segmented%20arch%20bridge